# Haskell - Assign variables with `case` in `do` block

Tags: haskell, monads

I have a small Haskell program whose behaviour needs to vary slightly depending on the number of arguments provided. I can't work out how to assign three variables in a neat way based on the number of arguments provided, though.

I want to use something like a `case` expression, or the equivalent of `switch` in other programming languages, but can't work out how.

Here is my current (faulty) code which relies on a `Dice.Base` module for random number generation:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Dice.Base
import System.Environment
import Data.List

main :: IO()

--Expected argument formats:
--(number of dice, number of faces on each die, number to add to total)
--(number of dice, number of faces on each die) 
--(number of faces on a single die)
main = do
        args  <- getArgs

        --Set the number of dice, number of faces on each die,
          --and number to add to sum of rolls.
        case (length args) of
          3 ->   let (numDice ::NaturalP) = toNaturalP $ read $ args!!0;
                 let (numFaces::NaturalP) = toNaturalP $ read $ args!!1;
                 let (offset  ::Integer ) = read $ args!!2;
          2 ->   let (numDice ::NaturalP) = toNaturalP $ read $ args!!0;
                 let (numFaces::NaturalP) = toNaturalP $ read $ args!!1;
                 let (offset  ::Integer ) = 0;
          1 ->   let (numDice ::NaturalP) = 1;
                 let (numFaces::NaturalP) = toNaturalP $ read $ args!!0;
                 let (offset  ::Integer ) = 0;

        -- 'dc' is a structure capturing the Dice Configuration.
        let dc = NumSidesPlus numDice numFaces offset
        outcomeInteger <- roll dc

        putStrLn("Dice configuration:     " ++ (show dc))
        putStrLn("Outcome:                " ++ (show outcomeInteger))
```

This doesn't work of course because `case` produces an expression; it isn't designed to work in the `do` block.

I know it's possible to do `let (a,b,c) = case ...` and assign the three values as a tuple, but I consider this a workaround because it really doesn't help me for more complex projects. What are the methods of flow control within a `do` block? Is there anything analogous to `switch` like in an imperative language?

How do I accomplish this dependent variable assignment?

Comment: Perhaps you could give a small example of the kind of complex logic for which tuples won't suffice.

Comment: @danidiaz - I'm struggling to think of a good example. But suppose I have `10` variables I want to assign-- although it's possible to do the assignment using tuples, I feel that it is somehow poor practice and messy to have it spread out over 10 lines. I like the approach of assigning variables one-by-one because I find it easier to read and understand.

Comment: At that point, perhaps the better approach would be to define a record with named fields to hold the parsed options, and also to use some of the existing argument-parsing libraries, like "optparse-generic" or the (more complex and full-featured) "optparse-applicative".

Comment: I wanted to suggest a wrapper like `with_default pos dflt = either (const def) id <$> tryIOError ((!! pos) <$> getArgs)`, but apparently I cannot figure out how to correctly catch whatever exception `!!` raises.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of switching of the length of the list and then indexing, I would rather pattern-match directly on the list while also using [`ViewPatterns`](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-12-02-view-patterns.html):

```
main :: IO ()
main = do 
    args  <- getArgs
    let (arg1,arg2) = case args of
                        [] -> (1::Int,"default")
                        [read -> arg1, read -> arg2] -> (arg1,arg2)
    print (arg1,arg2)
```

If a tuple isn't enough  because the extraction logic is complex, I would define a custom datatype holding the possible alternatives.

You can also use [guards](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pattern_guard) and the [`PatternGuards`](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/guide-to-ghc-extensions/pattern-and-guard-extensions#patternguards) extension to impose complex conditions on each match.

Comment: I like this; it's useful to know about the `ViewPatterns`. I know how to use `PatternGuards` and `case` and `if` statements for expression flow control, but are there any such flow control options inside a `do` block?

Comment: @Myridium You can use `case` and `if` in do-blocks, no problem. Notice that in your example the `let`s are inside the branches of the `case`. In my answer, the let  binds the result of the whole pattern-match, and the values are available in  the rest of the do-block. Theres a subtlety: inside do-blocks the `let`s do not have `in`s.

Answer (score 3):

You need to let bind your variables to an expression and have the expression determine the value, not assume you can do some pathalogical variable declaration:

```
let (numDice,numFaces,offset) =
     case (length args) of
      3 ->   (toNaturalP $ read $ args!!0
             ,toNaturalP $ read $ args!!1
             ,read $ args!!2)
      2 ->   (toNaturalP $ read $ args!!0
             ,toNaturalP $ read $ args!!1
             ,0)
      1 ->   (1
             ,toNaturalP $ read $ args!!0
             ,0)
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid grouping them into a tuple, because in general the conditional behaviour could be much more complex than just a handful of variable assignments. Is there an alternative way? Is there no option for flow control within the `do` block?

Comment: Also, this produces a parse error: `possible incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets` on the line with the `case` statement. I can't see an issue with indentation, though.

Comment: What I provided is a fragement - you need to embed it in the `do` block at the proper indentation.  WRT "control flow" what I am getting is that you want mutable variables or some sort of variables that escape their syntactic scope.  You can make mutable references but that is not as useful as you might hope Variables can not escape their scope.  You can declare variables "one-by-one" simply via `let numDice = expr1 ; numFaces = expr2 ; ...` but it seems those exprs will share a fair amount of logic in your case.

Comment: I did embed it in the `do` block and there is still an indentation problem. I indented the `case` line by just one more space and the compiler stopped grumbling.

Comment: Ah yes, the expression must be indented further than the variable name and I failed to do that - edited now.